# SQL select all from day of month

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with dates when the records were ordered. How do I select all dates on the "X" number of the month. So a table like so:

```
id      date
1      03/08/2014
2      03/21/2014
3      04/15/2014
4      04/19/2014
5      05/21/2014
```

after running the query would show records for both id 2, and 5 since both occurred on the 21st and today is the 21st.

Comment: `where day(date) = 21`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for probably. See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e92d87/1

```
select * from table1
where EXTRACT(DAY FROM `date`) = 
EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the records with day matching current day, then

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where DAY(date) = DAY(CURDATE())
```